# Download pdf files from local systems tomcat directory

Tags: java, pdf, jsf-2, download

I want to download a pdf file when user clicks on button.For front end I am using JSF 2.
Actually I want to download pdf files [download image](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileDownload.jsf)as shown in primefaces demo

pdf files are stored on my local tomcat's inside Root folder.
I am following in this way but it's giving me exception as

> java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 505 for
>   URL:

```
URL url;
        URLConnection con;
        DataInputStream dis; 
        FileOutputStream fos; 
        byte[] fileData;  
        try {
            url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/html/pdf/sample.pdf"); //File download Location goes here

            System.out.println("URL "+url.toString());
            con = url.openConnection(); // open the url connection.
            dis = new DataInputStream(con.getInputStream());
            fileData = new byte[con.getContentLength()]; 
            for (int q = 0; q < fileData.length; q++) { 
                fileData[q] = dis.readByte();
            }
            dis.close(); // close the data input stream
            fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("/Users/sample.pdf")); //FILE Save Location goes here
            fos.write(fileData);  // write out the file we want to save.
            fos.close(); // close the output stream writer
        }
        catch(Exception m) {
            System.out.println(m);
        }
```

> Is I am providing wrong path? If yes what is the correct path to
>   download file from local systems tomcat folder as shown ?

Answer (score 0):

I thing you forget to put `port number` `8080` OR `8052` or put your port number if you have changed.

put a specific path.it works

```
URL url;
URLConnection con;
DataInputStream dis; 
 FileOutputStream fos; 
 byte[] fileData;  
try {
url = new URL("http://localhost:8052/Naveed_workingfiles/a.pdf"); //File download Location goes here

System.out.println("URL "+url.toString());
con = url.openConnection(); // open the url connection.
dis = new DataInputStream(con.getInputStream());
fileData = new byte[con.getContentLength()]; 
for (int q = 0; q < fileData.length; q++) { 
    fileData[q] = dis.readByte();
}
dis.close(); // close the data input stream
fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/Documents and Settings/microsoft/My Documents/Downloads/sample.pdf")); //FILE Save Location goes here
fos.write(fileData);  // write out the file we want to save.
fos.close(); // close the output stream writer
}  catch(Exception m) {
System.out.println(m);
 }
```

Comment: what if he is running his tomcat on port 80

Comment: @shyan jogi then he ll put port 80..i have mention default port numbers.:D

Comment: for 80 its not required to put

Comment: @NK123 I have added port 8080 as I am using this port to run this application but it's giving me exception as `java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 505 for URL`

Comment: Enter the URL in your browser to see whether it works. Once it works, use the same URL in your code.

Comment: Yes @Rajesh J Advani If I am entering provided url as`http://localhost:8080/html/xml/sample.pdf` it's opening exact file as I wish

Comment: @NK123 Where exactly(path) you have stored pdf files . I have stored my pdf files under `\tomcat-7.0.23\webapps\ROOT\html\pdf\sample.pdf` this location & I tried your way still it's giving me error as `java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 505 for URL:`http://localhost:8080/html/pdf/sample.pdf

Comment: my all .pdf files on project folder. if i put one of file in sub folder i m getting same error.